# Bash PATH is not a valid identifier

Tags: bash, shell, path

I'm on a Mac, when I open my shell, it displays the following:

```
-bash: export: `/Users/jasoncollis/torch/install/bin/torch-activate:/usr/local/bin:/Users/jasoncollis/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:/Users/jasoncollis/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin': not a valid identifier
```

This is my #.bash_profile# file:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH=":/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# added by Anaconda3 4.2.0 installer
export PATH=":/Users/jasoncollis/anaconda/bin:$PATH"


# Added by Canopy installer on 2016-11-10
# VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT can be set to '' to make the bash prompt show that Canopy is active, otherwise 1
alias activate_canopy="source '/Users/jasoncollis/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate'"
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source '/Users/jasoncollis/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate'
export PATH=":/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8

export PATH=":/Users/jasoncollis/torch/install/bin/torch-activate:$PATH"

export PATH=":/Users/jasoncollis/torch/install/bin:$PATH"
```

I've been trying to search for a solution but nothing I've tried has worked so far. Would be really grateful for any help!

Comment: On a first look it looks like the quotes are not proper, `“` and `‘` type inverted quotes should be replaced by `"` and `'` respectively

Comment: And the last two `exports` should definitely be surrounded by `"` (not `'`) in order to interpolate the `$PATH` variable

Comment: I've replaced the single quotations with double and the type inverted quotes with the non-inverted ones and it still has the same problem :( - I'll edit the original with my updated #.bash_profile#

Comment: Please update the question accordingly so that we can see what you did

Comment: Done, sorry! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Usually this means that you have something like `export $PATH` instead of `export PATH` (note the absence of the preceding $ sign) somewhere in your script. But I don't see it in your post. What about the file that gets sourced? (`VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source '/Users/jasoncollis/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate'`)

Comment: Oh, and make sure that you edit the right file. Bash reads `.bash_profile`. Not sure why you refer to the file as `#.bash_profile#`. (Maybe some backup created by some editor or other script?)

Comment: I think I had the wrong file - was editing #.bash_profile#, not .bash_profile, and it's working now, thanks :) How can I mark this as resolved with no comments?

Comment: @afrischke, could you post your comment as an answer so Jason Collis can mark it as solved?

Comment: @SB87 Posted my comment as an answer, so that the question can be resolved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you edit the right file. For login shells Bash executes `.bash_profile` and not `#.bash_profile#`. The later looks like a backup file created by a text editor or script.